# How to add a correct rule for page rewriting in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a paginate system on my website.

Before, I had it :

```
RewriteRule ^famille/([^/]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /?fond=famille&id_rubrique=$1 [L]
```

And I could get to my page like this :

http://blabla.net/famille/131-articles_de_cave.html

So, now I add a rule for the paginate :

```
RewriteRule ^famille/([^/]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /?fond=famille&id_rubrique=$1&page=$3 [L]
```

If a go on :

http://blabla.net/famille/131-articles_de_cave-2.html (for the page two) it works.

But if I am on the fist page, I get 404 error :

http://blabla.net/famille/131-articles_de_cave.html

How fix this problem ? (I need to access on the first page without write the page number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using both rules or just one?

If you are using both rules in this order:

```
RewriteRule ^famille/([^/]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /fond=famille&id_rubrique=$1&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^famille/([^/]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /fond=famille&id_rubrique=$1 [L]
```

then the first group is not exclusive enough. The greedy match will match the first `-`. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^famille/([^-/]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /fond=famille&id_rubrique=$1&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^famille/([^-/]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /fond=famille&id_rubrique=$1 [L]
```

Or maybe just swap the rules?

PS: As per http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI you might want to leave out the `.html`...

Comment: Ah, just copy&pasted that from my test setup ;)

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen before the page number is your problem. Make it optional, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^famille/([^/]*)-([^-]*)-?([^-]*)\.html$ /?fond=famille&id_rubrique=$1&page=$3 [L]
```

Comment: It seems not work.

If I go here : http://blabla.net/famille/131-articles_de_cave-2.html

page is not in $_GET

Comment: Yep, for the reasons explained by @TobiX, the second match "eats" the hyphen and the number of the page doesn't end up where it's expected to be. Sorry about that, but I see your problem has been solved.